# Get Asp control id using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, client-side

I know that this question has been asked several times but I'm not able to solve this problem. My problem is simple how we get asp dropdown id using jQuery.

ASP

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNewPortfolioName" Width="150" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList>
```

JS

```
alert($("[id$='<%=ddlPortfolioName.ClientID %>']").val());
```

This logic not work for me it show undefined value, whether there are some value available in `dropdown` and out of these first one is selected. Please help me on this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use [ID Selector (“#id”)](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) you do not need attribute selector with wild card if you have only one item to get. As `ClientID` gives you complete and exact id of element.

```
alert($('#<%= ddlPortfolioName.ClientID %>').val());
```

If you are using framework 4 or above you can use [Control.ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to keep the Server id as ClientID

```
alert($('#ddlPortfolioName').val());
```

If you have dropdown in grid or repeater or listView then you will have to use contains wild card with attribute selector.

```
 $('[id*=ddlPortfolioName]').each(function(){
       alert($(this).val());
 });
```

Comment: Sorry this is not work for me also, can you suggest another solution

Comment: Is this dropdown in grid or repeater or listView?

Answer (score 0):

You need to select selected option and then get its value.use:

```
$('#<%=ddlPortfolioName.ClientID %> option:selected').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like dis

```
Var data=$("input[id*=ddlPortfolioName]").val();

alert(data);
```

or

```
alert($('#<%= ddlPortfolioName.ClientID %>').val());
```

or if its in child page..den u hv to pass the server side ID..for example my server side id is

```
alert($("#ctl00_MainContent_ddlPortfolioName").val());
```