# Bootstrap Datepicker not working with asp.net textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Files include in this are datepicker.css,jquery.min.js,datetimepicker.min.js
code as follow

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
<asp:TextBox ID='datetimepicker4'  runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
$('#datetimepicker4').datetimepicker(); 
 });
  </script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by not working ?

Comment: on selecting textbox the datepicker doesnt popup ! @Coder of Code

Comment: Possible issue is your jquery script is unable to find the id thats why event is not firing.Try using the `<%=datetimepicker4.ClientID%>` OR you can set the `ClientIDMode = Static` for `datetimepicker4`.

Comment: I think the ID selector won't work with *`runat="server"`*. Refer this **[Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21905347/3639582)**

Comment: i just check your option , but still doesn't work, with no errors @ Coder of Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code...

Add class "**input-append date**" in textbox

> CssClass="form-control input-append date"

---

And then apply date picker using this code.

```
$('[id$="datetimepicker2"]').datetimepicker({
    format: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss',
    language: 'en',
    pick12HourFormat: true
});
```

Comment: finally got it correct thanks kaushal khamar.How to display only date in it @kaushal khamar

Comment: You can disable Time Selection by using parameter


    "pickTime: false"

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
    $('#<%=datetimepicker4.ClientID %>').datetimepicker(); 
 });
</script>
```

When .NET render the control, the ID changes like this `ctl00_content1_datetimepicker4`.

Comment: If you work on js file : add 'ClientIDMode="Static"' in your textbox